# How many api calls blocktrail allow per second

Tags: api, blocktrail

How many api calls blocktrail allow per second. On official site mentioned only rate per minute(https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs#rate_limits). Is this mean that I can make 5 requests per second(or can I do more)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means you could do all 300 requests in 1 second if you really wanted to, and then wait 59 seconds for the next minute. Doesn't matter when you use them within that minute, just that no more than 300 are used per minute.